# Install CakePHP 2 Console on Ubuntu

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I've installed AMP on my Ubuntu. I love CakePHP and want to use it.

How can I use Bake Console on Ubuntu?

**Note**: `apt-get install cakephp-scripts` will install cakephp 1.3 scripts. but I'm using the latest version, 2.2.0

Answer (score 5):

You can also use console by providing php and cake.php paths.

```
/path/to/php /path/to/cake_2_2_0/app/Console/cake.php bake
```

Answer (score 3):

Once you have a CakePHP application on your machine, you just need to change to the app directory within the the application and run

```
app/Console/cake bake
```